# match groups with an inverted match

Tags: grep, regular-expression, group, pcregrep

I need to extract with `-o1` a group that is matched in lines that *do not* contain a string.

If I use `-v` pcregrep does not match any groups - which is reasonable: I'm asking to group-match something in patterns that I'm excluding.

How can I deal with that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your need correctly, if your match command takes the form `pcregrep -o1 '(match)'`, the corresponding regex that would report a match only if another string is not matched is `pcregrep -o1 '^(?!.*donotmatch).*(match)'`.
Look up negative lookahead expressions in the PCRE documentation. Also notice the `.*` in front of the `(match)`; this is needed due the anchoring of the negative looking ahead expression to the start of the line via the `^`

Comment: Thanks @iruvar, would it be the same regex as `(?<!.*donotmatch).*(match).*(?!.*donotmatch)` ?

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati, non-fixed length lookbehind assertions don't work. `(?<!.*donotmatch)` is not valid regex